# What do the semicolons of the following bit of code do?

Tags: syntax

I am trying to understand code used to solve the 100 doors problem of [rosettacode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/100_doors#Mathematica). The code in question is this

```
n=100;
tmp=ConstantArray[-1,n];
Do[tmp[[i;;;;i]]*=-1;,{i,n}];
Do[Print["door ",i," is ",If[tmp[[i]]==-1,"closed","open"]],
{i,1,Length[tmp]}]
```

I understand every line except the third. I have never seen the construct

```
Do[tmp[[i;;;;i]]*=-1;,{i,n}];
```

what do these semicolons inside a list do. What is the * for?

Comment: Look at the `FullForm`, e.g., `Hold[tmp[[i;;;;i]]] //FullForm` or `Hold[tmp[[i ;; ;; i]] *= -1] // FullForm`

Comment: also see [Span](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html) and [TimesBy](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TimesBy.html)

Comment: Ok, now i get it. Thank you both

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Answer (score 1):

I look in the help that aaa[[b;;c;;d]] is understood as Part from b to c in steps of d. Then if c is missed that means to the end. Only the positions that are squares are opened. So it cames from this [[b;; ;;d]]